# SQL Developer connectivity error with Oracle DB 12C

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

**Error: Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**

I am extremely new to Oracle DB setup and connectivity and am facing issue in connecting SQL Developer with Oracle DB.

Steps followed:

1) Installed Oracle DB 12c. The following are the installation details:

Oracle base: D:\app\admin\virtual

Software Location: D:\app\admin\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1

Database file location: D:\app\admin\virtual\oradata

Database edition: Standard Edition 2 (5.5GB)

Character set: Unicode (AL32UTF8)

Global database name: orcl.abc.com

password: ******

Pluggable database name: orclpdb

Note: Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Express URL: https://localhost:5500/em

2) Tried connecting to the DB wih sqlplus and it connected like a charm, PFB:

```
C:\Users\Aakash.basu>sqlplus  sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jun 26 17:15:28 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

3) Unzipped and opened **Oracle SQL Developer** and gave:

a) A name

b) username (tried with): system, sys and pdbadmin

c) password as is given

d) Hostname: localhost

e) port: 1521

f) SID: First used default **xe** (which gave me the error: Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor), so tried with **CLRExtProc** from **tnsnames.ora** file

But now, the error is, **Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**

It is a **Windows 10 Machine with x64 based processor**. Please let me know if you need any further details.

What to do? Please help!

Edit: Even though the question is a duplicate of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851161/oracle-database-12c-error-while-trying-to-connect-the-network-adapter-could-not) but none of the answers could solve my problem.

First ans:
a) Tried step 1, all fine.

b) Already shared the sqlplus successful connectivity above

c) Tried doing tnsping localhost and it is working with OK (check below):

> C:\Users\Aakash.basu>tnsping localhost
>
> TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
>   on 27-JUN-2019 00:12:22
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>   D:\app\admin\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
>
> Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias Attempting to contact
>   (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
>   OK (30 msec)

d) Tried starting listener, check below:

> C:\Users\Aakash.basu>lsnrctl start
>
> LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on
>   27-JUN-2019 00:18:42
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been
>   started

e) Renamed SQLNET.ORA file but still no use.

Trial from other answers from the above question are already included in the edit above.

**Edit 2**: I ran the **lsnrctl status** command and got this:

```
C:\Users\Aakash.basu>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-JUN-2019 01:11:52

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                27-JUN-2019 01:05:28
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 6 min. 31 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\admin\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         D:\app\admin\virtual\diag\tnslsnr\ab-LPT\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ab-LPT.abc.com)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle database 12c Error while trying to connect: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851161/oracle-database-12c-error-while-trying-to-connect-the-network-adapter-could-not)

Comment: I tried all the answers from the link given by you and all of them are correctly working in my system, still the error. Any help?

Comment: Updated with an edit to all the points from the other question, still stuck. Please help?

Comment: Try `lsnrctl status`. That should show you what instances are available to connect to. From your description above it sounds like you want SID=orcl to connect to the CDB, or service name = orclpdb if you want to connect to the PDB.

Comment: I've updated edit 2 with the lsnrctl status command's return. I think am already connecting to the right instance, i.e, CLRExtProc. Something else is the issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue as yours, try by opening Oracle net manager application which should be installed with Oracle 12c.

Under **Oracle Net Configuration** -> **Local** -> **Service Naming**
In system service name, `SID` was disabled and `Service name` was enabled so in SQL Developer when I tried by connecting it with service name, the test connection passed.

All the best for resolving the issue if this does not help